# RSA шифрование в QT C++

Tags: c++, windows, qt, rsa, криптография

Подскажите ссылки и примеры, где шифрование выполняется приватным ключом RSA, а дешифрование - публичным.

Решение нужно будет подключить к QT

Ключ в pem формате (base64).

Обычно везде используется шифрование публичным ключом и дешифровка приватным, а мне надо наоборот.

Comment: То, что вы описали - подписывание ЭЦП. Попробуйте поискать так. Непосредственно шифрование или расшифровка могут быть произведены примитивом BN_mod_exp из OpenSSL, например.

Comment: Обычно ЭЦП это короткий хеш в итоге? мне же нужно полноценное шифрование.

Comment: ЭЦП - результат применения RSA с приватным ключом в качестве ключа.

Comment: А вообще - вопрос слишком общий, потому что криптобиблиотек чуть менее чем много: OpenSSL, MbedTLS/PolarSSL, LibreSSL, Crypto++, CryptoAPI, и бесконечное множество прочих.

Comment: Мне бы хоть какое-то стабильное решение, где есть нормально реализованная опция и вменяемые настройки, я не привязан к конкретно одной.

Comment: Функция RSA_private_encrypt из OpenSSL

Answer (score 1):

Совсем недавно для решения этой задачи [QuasarApp](https://github.com/QuasarApp) выпустили простую [библиотеку](https://github.com/QuasarApp/Qt-Secret) для rsa шифрования в Qt.
Подробная статья о том как пользоваться есть [здесь](https://evileg.com/ru/post/496/).

Comment: Хорошо. Заглянул, посмотрел.

Comment: Данная библиотека не привязывается к openSSL как qca и легко подключается к qmake проектам)

Answer (score 1):

Для Qt попробуйте [QCA](https://userbase.kde.org/QCA) (Qt Cryptographic Architecture). Документация в архиве. Пример использования `RSA` можно глянуть [тут](https://github.com/KDE/qca/blob/master/examples/rsatest/rsatest.cpp).

Comment: Спасибо! Очень признателен!